# Dev lap vs server setup

Tags: 2010

I am developing web applications for a SharePoint farm. On my laptop, I've attempted to setup my SharePoint site (I'm running Windows 7) as close as possible to the SharePoint site (Server 2008) on the farm. I had the administrator create a site template for me, but when I try to install it, I get errors saying that there are features on the farm that I do not have on my laptop (SSRS for one). Is there a way for the administrator to export the site from the farm so i can import without getting all the features not installed errors and without me installing all the features the server farm has?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: no.

Long answer is: You may be able to open the template package and modify, e.g., the onet.xml of the template and remove references to features you don't have. But, in the end, *it is quicker/less risky/less headache to just install the missing components*. Really, this is just theoretical long answer, don't seriously consider this alternative :)

Comment: agreed, and I'd like to add - use a server for this kind of development.  Windows 7 is nice for demos and learning but not suitable for real-world work.